# how to display values in select tag as 10,15,20,25 using grails select tag

Tags: grails

how to display in select tag options values as 10,15,20,25 using grails select tag

```
<g:select  name="maxpage" from="${10..30}" />
```

10

15

20

25
.
.
.
1000

> i wanted to display in this format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use an array for the `from` attribute :

```
<g:select  name="maxpage" from="${[10,15,20,25]}" />
```

***Update:***

Assuming you would like to give a selection between 10 and 1000 with steps of 5 you could try this:

```
<g:select  name="maxpage" from="${(10..1000).step(5)}" />
```

Comment: thanx for your answer.. but i want till 1000.. so its too much to type like this until 1000